# Rails Prawn UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I am new to rails and I am trying to use Prawm to generate pdf's. I am getting this error:
ActionController::UnknownFormat

Here is the code:

```
def show_deposited_checks

deposit_id = params[:format]

if deposit_id.present?
  @payments = Payment.where(:deposit_id => deposit_id)
      respond_to do |format|
              format.html
              format.pdf do
                pdf = Prawn::Document.new
                pdf.text "Hello World"
                send_data pdf.render
                end 
      end        
else
  @payments = Payment.all.limit(10)
end
```

end

I an redirecting from here:

```
redirect_to show_deposited_checks_payments_path(deposit)
```

I have another method that works just fine so I suspect it has something to do with the redirect and the way the controller is receiving the data. Any help with be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that where doesn't execute immediately. There's probably a better way(I'm fairly new to Rails too), but I think this should work:

@payments = Payment.where(:deposit_id => deposit_id).take(10) #or how ever many you want included